# Second Accordion Won't Show

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an accordion and I want to add another next to it but it just won't show for some reason and I don't understand why. I put the code in the tryit editor v3.6 online and it's showing fine. I am using the latest versions of every script, except the bootstrap 5 beta instead, I'm using 4.5.

PS: Stackoverflow won't let me post until I say more but I don't have more so I will add some lorem ipsum: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras auctor augue mauris, ac vehicula lorem dignissim sit amet. Donec consectetur risus a placerat lobortis. Mauris posuere sapien ac arcu facilisis, non pellentesque diam semper. Etiam luctus vehicula dictum. Sed pellentesque augue eros, sed venenatis ex scelerisque a. Sed luctus tristique.

```
 <div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a href="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                Question One
              </a>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat
              amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod
              voluptatibus modi rerum laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a href="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                Question Two
              </a>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat
              amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod
              voluptatibus modi rerum laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a href="#collapseThree" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                Question Three
              </a>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat
              amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod
              voluptatibus modi rerum laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="accordion2">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a href="#collapseFour" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2">
                Question Four
              </a>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat
              amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod
              voluptatibus modi rerum laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a href="#collapseFive" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2">
                Question Five
              </a>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat
              amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod
              voluptatibus modi rerum laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a href="#collapseSix" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2">
                Question Six
              </a>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseSix" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat
              amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod
              voluptatibus modi rerum laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

I think the problem is your id at `<div id="accordion2">`.
You can find it right before you Accordion "Question Four".
I tried your code and changed the id from "accordion2" to "accordion".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <title>Accordion</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="accordion">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a href="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                    Question One
                  </a>
              </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse">
              <div class="card-body">
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod voluptatibus modi rerum
                laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a href="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                    Question Two
                  </a>
              </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse">
              <div class="card-body">
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod voluptatibus modi rerum
                laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a href="#collapseThree" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                    Question Three
                  </a>
              </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse">
              <div class="card-body">
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod voluptatibus modi rerum
                laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a href="#collapseFour" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                  Question Four
                </a>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod voluptatibus modi rerum
              laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a href="#collapseFive" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                  Question Five
                </a>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod voluptatibus modi rerum
              laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a href="#collapseSix" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                  Question Six
                </a>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseSix" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ea officiis distinctio exercitationem dolor minus placeat amet commodi, ab a perspiciatis officia nobis reiciendis numquam totam repudiandae molestias nulla, quod voluptatibus modi rerum
              laboriosam tenetur. Nihil, soluta eaque? Minima, deserunt.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried it the first time that way but it's displaying the following error: The id value [ accordion ] must be unique. I think the problem is with the scripts but I don't understand how or why.

Comment: @DatMan I edited my answer and added my code. I removed div with id of "accordion2" and changed the data-parent to #accordion. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It's still not solving the problem even though I use the same scripts as you did. The weird thing is that I follow the tutorial of traversy media where he does the same thing and same code but uses older versions of  bootstrap min.css, bootstrap min.js jquery and popper.min.js and it works for him. I tried copying the older versions from his file and it starts working. So still I don't see the problem...